# Преобразовать кнопки

Tags: c#, kotlin

Здраствуйте. Когда я программировал в c#, там была следующая команда `b = (Button)sender;`, которая преобразовывала объекты в кнопку. Можно сделать такое в Kotlin.

Comment: Это называется `type cast`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно

```
val b = sender as Button
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @RoyaleXPlay Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.